# Getting a 3-Legged Token with Authorization Code Grant

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

I am currently trying to complete this step by step tutorial which is based on [Getting a 3-Legged Token with Authorization Code Grant](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/)

here is my cURL code:

```
curl -v "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/gettoken" 
-X POST 
-H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
-d "client_id=****&
    client_secret=****&
    grant_type=authorization_code&
    code=1O4F-z9gXRtGlBymcGoD3bV3Ws2cqqjeN78PpgGn&
    redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/api/forge/callback/oauth"
```

here is the error I am stuck with:

```
{"developerMessage":"The authorization code/refresh token is expired or 
invalid/redirect_uri must have the same value as in the authorization 
request.","userMessage":"","errorCode":"AUTH-004","more 
info":"http://developer.api.autodesk.com/documentation/v1/errors/AUTH-004"}* 
Connection #0 to host developer.api.autodesk.com left intact
```

Note:

- I have double checked that the URI is the same as my callback URL on the forge application.
- The spacing on the cURL code is simply for visual reasons, this is not how it is ran within my command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's going on is that the *code* you get after the user logs in has an extremely short expiration time. After all, the `POST /authentication/v1/gettoken` endpoint is meant to be called immediately after the user logs in.

Btw. I went through the same steps, and since it took me a while to create a Postman request with the *code* I received, I ended up with the same error as you. Then, when I requested another *code* and immediately re-sent the Postman request, it succeeded.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help :) Cheers!

Comment: I am having the similar issue. I want to know for how long the authorization code is valid?

Comment: I don't think this is specified anywhere but in my experience it's just "short enough"" period of time that if you try and debug things before calling the `gettoken` endpoint, it'll be too late.